# No Filesystem for scheme 'abfss' with spark-on-k8s Operator

Tags: azure, apache-spark, kubernetes, azure-data-lake

I am trying to run a very simple spark job that will Extract some data from my Azure Data Lake and print it on screen using the [spark-on-k8s operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator).
For that I have built an image using a Dockerfile that looks like this:

```
FROM gcr.io/spark-operator/spark-py:v3.1.1

USER root:root

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY jars/ /opt/spark/jars
COPY simple-etl-job.py /app
WORKDIR /app

USER 1001
```

And when I launch it as a job on Kubernetes it returns me an error saying:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o56.load.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: abfss
```

The strange thing is, I am copying to the `/opt/spark/jars` directory the same jars used for a local `spark-submit` job that does the same as my K8s code and runs successfully.
Those jars are:

- hadoop-azure-3.2.0.jar
- wildfly-openssl-1.0.4.Final.jar
- hadoop-azure-datalake-3.2.0.jar

What else could I possibly be doing wrong?

P.S.: Here is my spark CRD:

```yaml
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: simple-spark-etl-job
  namespace: spark-operator
spec:
  type: Python
  mode: cluster
  image: "<my-org>/<my-image>:<my-tag>"
  imagePullPolicy: Always
  mainApplicationFile: "local:///app/simple-etl-job.py"
  sparkVersion: "3.1.1"
  restartPolicy:
    type: OnFailure
    onFailureRetries: 3
    onFailureRetryInterval: 10
    onSubmissionFailureRetries: 5
    onSubmissionFailureRetryInterval: 20
  driver:
    cores: 1
    coreLimit: "1200m"
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
    serviceAccount: default
  executor:
    cores: 1
    instances: 2
    memory: "512m"
    labels:
      version: 3.1.1
```

Comment: Hello @Murilo Mendonça , Please were you able to figure this out!!? optimizing same architecture as yours and I am suck on this particular error message, what step did you take to figure this out? thanks

Comment: Hi @Sillians, no I could not and since my team de-prioritized this demand, I did not continue working on a solution. If you figure it out, let me know!

Comment: Hello @Murilo Mendonça , thanks for the feedback. Yes, I did. Had to use a different spark-operator image,  here is the image: [spark-py:v3.1.1-hadoop3](https://gcr.io/spark-operator/spark-py@sha256:bf2fcd77f2b24bbd812c7a2d3635b6f1d3691d9da53996e1d615a9fbd572b314) , and add the necessary jar files that would help establish connection to Azure Storage Gen2, from maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here maybe  occuring due openssl installed versions being  not compatible with `wildfly-openssl-*.jar` in new machine or environment or when adding the hadoop-azure package in the Docker image .

Please check if Upgrading wildfly-openssl-*.final.jar to latest version helps . Also Check for JDK versioning mismatch

Also See if order of jars is making any difference as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454868/databricks-connect-fails-with-no-filesystem-for-scheme-abfss)

Comment: Both Spark and JDK are on the same versions on my local machine and the Docker image. It does not seem to be something with the wildfly jar, because the "no scheme abfss" is an error thrown only when I don't have the `hadoop-azure-datalake-3.2.0.jar` in the proper directory. I will also give it a give a try and let you know.

Comment: as suspected, no changes in the errors thrown with updating wildfly jar as well